# Why codeblocks is giving runtime error after getting output?

Tags: runtime-error, c++14

The below code is giving runtime error after printing output for large value but if i use small values then its working fine.In this code we need to find next smallest palindrome.
e.g. 9999 gives output 10001 which is correct and no runtime error but
999999999999999999999999999999 gives correct output but after getting output codeblocks displays the ran26.cpp is stopped working and in ideone it gives runtime error after printing output.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        int carry=1,flag=0,flag2=0;
        string str,str2;
        cin>>str;
        int len=str.size();
        while(1)
        {
        int ch[len];
        flag=0;flag2=0;
        carry=1;
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
            ch[i]=str[i]-'0';
        for(int i=len-1;i>=0;i--)
            {
            int x=ch[i];
            ch[i]=(x+carry)%10;
            carry=(x+carry)/10;
            }
        while(carry>0)
            {
            ch[len]=carry%10;
            len++;
            carry=carry/10;
            flag=1;
            }
            if(flag==1)
            {
                int start=0,end=len-1,temp1;
                while (start < end)
                {
                temp1 = ch[start];
                ch[start] = ch[end];
                ch[end] = temp1;
                start++;
                end--;
                }
            }
            for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
            {
                str[i]=ch[i]+'0';
                str2[len-1-i]=ch[i]+'0';
            }
            for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
            {
                if(str[i]!=str2[i])
                    flag2=1;
            }
            if(flag2==0)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
                    cout<<str[i];
                cout<<endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You access `ch` and `str2` out of bounds in at least two places. Consider using a debugger or a tool like Valgrind .

Comment: Thanks BTW i figured it out actually i was accessing the str and str2 position which was giving array out of bound just used resize function to resize str and str2.

Comment: In the `while(carry>0)` loop, `ch[len]=carry%10;` is out of bounds, and `len++;` makes it worse each iteration.

Comment: I simply initialized ch[10000000] at top now its not getting in array out of bound.

Comment: Someday you may want to consider writing code that works because it is correct, not because you just made buffers larger until it didn't crash. :)

Comment: Yes you are saying right i will definetly look to make it correct anyway thanks.